# Singleton letters in direct speech

Tags: punctuation, writing, dialogue

I am writing a scene where one of the characters screams, "H" and "O-H." I want to know the best to indicate that to the reader, that the distinct letters are being pronounced, not Oh, but O and H. I am also doubtful that "H!" might not be clear as the letter 'H' and might be taken as a mild interjection, like "hmmm." Hence I was considering "'H'!" but that looks just as messy and confusing. Also about O,H, should I present it as "O-H!", "'O', 'H!'" or is there some better convention? Any help is appreciated and this might just be a question on punctuation. I also want to emphasize the pronunciation of the letters, "H" as "Eechh," so is that a viable option or should I just describe that in the paragraph following the dialogue?

Comment: H is usually spelled as *aitch* or *haitch* (pronunciation can vary and can be a shibboleth in certain areas).

Comment: I don't think 'H' could be misunderstood as an interjection. 'O' is obviously ambiguous. I assume your character is calling out initials, but someone hearing them wouldn't necessarily know that. Is it essential for the reader to know? Can it become clear later on?

Comment: @KateBunting It's an organic chemistry class and he's calling out the hydrogen atoms and hydroxyl groups as he goes. It's not essential to the story but it's an experience I'd like the reader to have. It might be clear if the reader has a pre-existing knowledge about carbohydrates, I don't plan on introducing a glucose structure in a fiction novel.

Comment: If it's clear from the context of a chemistry class that the letters represent the names of elements, I don't see a problem with misunderstanding. I thought at first that the initials were a clue in a murder mystery or something, that the reader would only learn the significance of later.

Comment: So to close the discussion, @KateBunting, which is the preferred way to present it? (In terms of punctuation and spelling of the letters.) I'd ask for the best way but this is a stackexchange website for discussion on a liberal art.

Comment: 'He called out "H!" and "OH!"' (with or without exclamation marks) would be fine, I think. Chemical symbols in combination are written without punctuation between them.